# Put request Tasks on hold until some other request Task finishes and then resume them

Tags: c#, httprequest, windows-8.1, threadpool, windows-phone-8.1

My scenario is this: I have an Http Authentication request in my app that returns an access token that will be used for subsequent Http requests.
I can have several requests executing at the same time, but they need a valid access token, so before every request I check if the access token is valid.
If it is inexistent or invalid, I have to create another Authentication request to retrieve a new access token. The thing is, every other request must wait for the answer of this request before execution. Also I can't have two Authentication requests running at the same time, the new must wait for the old to finish before executing.

So, how can I have a collection of requests that I can just say: "If the access token is invalid wait for this new Authentication request I'm gonna do before executing your requests"?

Comment: The condition for other requests to wait for a success of a current one is strange. I can think of a dozen methods to fool your authentication or bring down the web site. What's wrong with *standard* authentication approaches? Did you look at them first before inventing a new square wheel?

Comment: This is how my app operates, the Authentication request is different from the others, so I cannot make one normal request return a new access token from the server, it needs to call a new Authentication for a new token.

Comment: I would urge you to reconsider what you trying to develop. Don't roll your own security. Search for "c# authentication <your server side tech>", for example: "c# authentication asp.net web api". Read it up, it is all there and implemented. You just have to hook it up and use properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to roll your own type which will manage the access token's lifetime based on your requirements:

```
class AccessTokenManager
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim Mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private AccessToken LastSeenToken;

    public async Task<AccessToken> ResolveToken(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await this.Mutex.WaitAsync(ct);

        try
        {
            if (this.LastSeenToken == null || !this.LastSeenToken.IsValid)
            {
                this.LastSeenToken = await this.GetNewAuthTokenAsync(ct);
            }

            return this.LastSeenToken;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Mutex.Release();
        }
    }

    private async Task<AccessToken> GetNewAuthTokenAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // Pure retrieve new token implementation.
    }
}
```

*Note: `ConfigureAwait(false)` omitted for brevity.*

Then whenever you need the valid token (at the beginning of each request, presumably), you just use `await AccessTokenManagerInstance.ResolveToken`, which will either go out and get a new valid token for you, or spit out the cached one. You could implement the manager as a singleton if you know you will only ever need a single instance in your application.